# Rsync --backup-dir seems to be ignored

Tags: rsync

I want to use `rsync` to backup a directory from a local location to a remote location, and store changed files in another remote location. I did use:

```
rsync -rcvhL --progress --backup \
  --backup-dir=user@url.com:/home/user/Changes/`date +%Y.%m.%d` . \
  user@url.com:/home/user/Files/
```

The `--backup-dir` stays empty, while it should be filled. Is it possible what I'm trying to accomplish is not possible or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> --backup-dir=DIR
>
> In combination with the --backup option, this tells rsync to store all backups in the specified directory on the receiving
> side. This can be used for incremental backups. You can additionally
> specify a backup suffix using the --suffix option (otherwise the files
> backed up in the specified directory will keep their original
> filenames).

Keyword, `receiving side`. So, the correct syntax is `--backup-dir=/path/on/destination/server` Hope that answers your question.

When I saw your syntax I got a little bit excited for a second, because I thought that it became capable of redirecting the backed up files to another server.